# print four last values of each row of a list in python

Tags: python

I need to print the four last values of each row of the list CoordSt.
My code gives the following error:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
for i,j,numSt,x,y,z in coordSt:
    f = open('file_name','w')
    f.write('%s,%s,%s,%s \n'(numSt,x,y,z))
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You omitted the `%` operator:

```
f.write('%s,%s,%s,%s \n' % (numSt,x,y,z))
                         ^
```

The whole code cleaned up a bit:

```
with open("file_name", "w") as f:
    for row in coordSt:
        f.write("%s,%s,%s,%s\n" % row[-4:])
```

Comment: Yes, it deletes every row and only the last is written. Any advise?

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the formatting `%`:

`f.write('%s,%s,%s,%s \n' %(numSt,x,y,z))`